# In a Django QuerySet, how to filter for "not exists" in a many-to-one relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have two models like this:

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()

class Report(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

In reality each model has more fields which are of no consequence to this question.

I want to filter all users who have an email which starts with 'a' and have no reports. There will be more `.filter()` and `.exclude()` criteria based on other fields.

I want to approach it like this:

```
users = User.objects.filter(email__like = 'a%')

users = users.filter(<other filters>)

users = ???
```

I would like ??? to filter out users who do not have reports associated with them. How would I do this? If this is not possible as I have presented it, what is an alternate approach?

Comment: [Generic solution for Django 1.11+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51879399/476716)

Answer (score 125, accepted):

**Note: this answer was written in 2013 for Django 1.5. See the other answers for better approaches that work with newer versions of Django**

Use [`isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-isnull).

```
users_without_reports = User.objects.filter(report__isnull=True)
users_with_reports = User.objects.filter(report__isnull=False).distinct()
```

When you use `isnull=False`, the `distinct()` is required to prevent duplicate results.

Comment: This is OK, but it generates an `OUTER JOIN` with `report` in the case of both `__isnull=True` and `__isnull=False`. For the  question about users with reports it may be less efficient than an `INNER JOIN`. I have found an ugly hack for exactly this case: `User.objects.filter(report__id__gt=0).distinct()`. This assumes IDs are > 0, which needs not be a case. Any better way of forcing an inner join, anyone?

Comment: @OrangeDog it would be useful to explain why it's better, even if that's as simple as "Using NOT EXISTS is (usually?) more efficient that doing a join"

Comment: @OrangeDog Fair point, but I was hoping you could confirm whether or not it gives better performance. Given that the question doesn't include any SQL, I'm not sure the OP specifically wanted a query using `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: @Alasdair yes, it will almost always be faster to use `WHERE NOT EXISTS` than a `DISTINCT ... OUTER JOIN`, as it avoids the possibly gigantic intermediate result set.

Comment: where is this behaviour documented?

Answer (score 105):

As of Django 3.0 you can now use expressions directly in a `filter()`, removing the unnecessary SQL clause:

```py
User.objects.filter(
    ~Exists(Reports.objects.filter(user=OuterRef('pk'))),
    email__startswith='a'
)
```

```sql
SELECT user.pk, user.email
FROM user
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT U0.pk FROM reports U0 WHERE U0.user = user.pk) AND email LIKE 'a%';
```

Docs:

- [Exists](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries)
- [OuterRef](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.OuterRef)
- [Filtering on a Subquery() or Exists() expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#filtering-on-a-subquery-or-exists-expressions)

---

For Django 1.11+ you can add `EXISTS` subqueries:

```py
User.objects.annotate(
    no_reports=~Exists(Reports.objects.filter(user__eq=OuterRef('pk')))
).filter(
    email__startswith='a',
    no_reports=True
)
```

This generates SQL something like this:

```sql
SELECT
    user.pk,
    user.email,
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT U0.pk FROM reports U0 WHERE U0.user = user.pk) AS no_reports
FROM user
WHERE email LIKE 'a%' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT U0.pk FROM reports U0 WHERE U0.user = user.pk);
```

A `NOT EXISTS` clause is almost always the most efficient way to do a "not exists" filter.

---

Comment: This should be the top answer. Thank you @OrangeDog.

Comment: Got this error: `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: eq` using `Django==3.2.7`. Had to change `user__eq=OuterRef('pk')` to **`user=OuterRef('pk')`** which fixed the error. I guess it's slightly changed in latest version of Django.

Answer (score 12):

The only way to get native SQL EXISTS/NOT EXISTS without extra queries or JOINs is to add it as raw SQL in the .extra() clause:

```
users = users.extra(where=[
    """NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM {reports} 
                  WHERE user_id={users}.id)
    """.format(reports=Report._meta.db_table, users=User._meta.db_table)
])
```

In fact, it's a pretty obvious and efficient solution and I sometimes wonder why it wasn't built in to Django as a lookup. Also it allows to refine the subquery to find e.g. only users with[out] a report during *last week*, or with[out] an unanswered/unviewed report.

Comment: @OrangeDog params can not be used to pass table names. They would be quoted by the DB engine. Also it is of no use to additionally secure the table names because they come from the code, not from user input.

Comment: what’s wrong with quoting table names? Depending on what they are they might need to be quoted. That’s one reason you should use params.

Comment: @OrangeDog - because most database engines interpret single quotes as string literals - tables need to be double/angle quoted, or not quoted at all

Answer (score 6):

In addition to @OrangeDog answer. [Since Django 3.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#filtering-on-a-subquery-or-exists-expressions) you can use `Exists` subquery to directly filter a queryset:

```
User.objects.filter(
    ~Exists(Reports.objects.filter(user__eq=OuterRef('pk'))
)
```

Answer (score 4):

[Alasdair's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14832060/4794) is helpful, but I don't like using `distinct()`. It can sometimes be useful, but it's usually a code smell telling you that you messed up your joins.

Luckily, Django's [queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#in) lets you filter on subqueries. With Django 3.0, you can also use an [exists clause](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#filtering-on-a-subquery-or-exists-expressions).

Here are a few ways to run the queries from your question:

```
# Tested with Django 3.0 and Python 3.6
import logging
import sys

import django
from django.apps import apps
from django.apps.config import AppConfig
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import connections, models, DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase

NAME = 'udjango'
DB_FILE = NAME + '.db'


def main():
    setup()

    class User(models.Model):
        email = models.EmailField()

        def __repr__(self):
            return 'User({!r})'.format(self.email)

    class Report(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    syncdb(User)
    syncdb(Report)

    anne = User.objects.create(email='anne@example.com')
    User.objects.create(email='adam@example.com')
    alice = User.objects.create(email='alice@example.com')
    User.objects.create(email='bob@example.com')

    Report.objects.create(user=anne)
    Report.objects.create(user=alice)
    Report.objects.create(user=alice)

    logging.info('users without reports')
    logging.info(User.objects.filter(report__isnull=True, email__startswith='a'))

    logging.info('users with reports (allows duplicates)')
    logging.info(User.objects.filter(report__isnull=False, email__startswith='a'))

    logging.info('users with reports (no duplicates)')
    logging.info(User.objects.exclude(report__isnull=True).filter(email__startswith='a'))

    logging.info('users with reports (no duplicates, simpler SQL)')
    report_user_ids = Report.objects.values('user_id')
    logging.info(User.objects.filter(id__in=report_user_ids, email__startswith='a'))

    logging.info('users with reports (EXISTS clause, Django 3.0)')
    logging.info(User.objects.filter(
        Exists(Report.objects.filter(user_id=OuterRef('id'))),
        email__startswith='a'))

    logging.info('Done.')


def setup():
    with open(DB_FILE, 'w'):
        pass  # wipe the database
    settings.configure(
        DEBUG=True,
        DATABASES={
            DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS: {
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
                'NAME': DB_FILE}},
        LOGGING={'version': 1,
                 'disable_existing_loggers': False,
                 'formatters': {
                    'debug': {
                        'format': '%(asctime)s[%(levelname)s]'
                                  '%(name)s.%(funcName)s(): %(message)s',
                        'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'}},
                 'handlers': {
                    'console': {
                        'level': 'DEBUG',
                        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                        'formatter': 'debug'}},
                 'root': {
                    'handlers': ['console'],
                    'level': 'INFO'},
                 'loggers': {
                    "django.db": {"level": "DEBUG"}}})
    app_config = AppConfig(NAME, sys.modules['__main__'])
    apps.populate([app_config])
    django.setup()
    original_new_func = ModelBase.__new__

    @staticmethod
    def patched_new(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        if 'Meta' not in attrs:
            class Meta:
                app_label = NAME
            attrs['Meta'] = Meta
        return original_new_func(cls, name, bases, attrs)
    ModelBase.__new__ = patched_new


def syncdb(model):
    """ Standard syncdb expects models to be in reliable locations.

    Based on https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.3
    /django/core/management/commands/migrate.py#L285
    """
    connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
    with connection.schema_editor() as editor:
        editor.create_model(model)


main()
```

If you put that into a Python file and run it, you should see something like this:

```
2019-12-06 11:45:17[DEBUG]django.db.backends.debug_sql(): (0.000) PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF; args=None
2019-12-06 11:45:17[DEBUG]django.db.backends.debug_sql(): (0.000) PRAGMA foreign_keys; args=None
2019-12-06 11:45:17[DEBUG]django.db.backends.debug_sql(): (0.000) BEGIN; args=None
2019-12-06 11:45:17[DEBUG]django.db.backends.schema.execute(): CREATE TABLE "udjango_user" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "email" varchar(254) NOT NULL); (params None)
2019-12-06 11:45:17[DEBUG]django.db.backends.debug_sql(): (0.000) CREATE TABLE "udjango_user" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "email" varchar(254) NOT NULL); args=None
2019-12-06 11:45:17[DEBUG]django.db.backends.debug_sql(): (0.000) PRAGMA foreign_key_check; args=None
2019-12-06 11:45:17[DEBUG]django.db.backends.debug_sql(): (0.000) PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON; args=None
2019-12-06 11:45:17[DEBUG]django.db.backends.debug_sql(): (0.000) PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF; args=None
2019-12-06 11:45:17[DEBUG]django.db.backends.debug_sql(): (0.000) PRAGMA foreign_keys; args=None
2019-12-06 11:45:17[DEBUG]django.db.backends.debug_sql(): (0.000) BEGIN; args=None
2019-12-06 11:45:17[DEBUG]django.db.backends.schema.execute(): CREATE TABLE "udjango_report" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "user_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "udjango_user" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED); (params None)
2019-12-06 11:45:17[DEBUG]django.db.backends.debug_sql(): (0.000) CREATE TABLE "udjango_report" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "user_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "udjango_user" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED); args=None
2019-12-06 11:45:17[DEBUG]django.db.backends.debug_sql(): (0.000) PRAGMA foreign_key_check; args=None
2019-12-06 11:45:17[DEBUG]django.db.backends.schema.execute(): CREATE INDEX "udjango_report_user_id_60bc619c" ON "udjango_report" ("user_id"); (params ())
2019-12-06 11:45:17[DEBUG]django.db.backends.debug_sql(): (0.000) CREATE INDEX "udjango_report_user_id_60bc619c" ON "udjango_report" ("user_id"); args=()
2019-12-06 11:45:17[DEBUG]django.db.backends.debug_sql(): (0.000) PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON; args=None
2019-12-06 11:45:17[DEBUG]django.db.backends.debug_sql(): (0.017) INSERT INTO "udjango_user" ("email") VALUES ('anne@example.com'); args=['anne@example.com']
2019-12-06 11:45:17[DEBUG]django.db.backends.debug_sql(): (0.023) INSERT INTO "udjango_user" ("email") VALUES ('adam@example.com'); args=['adam@example.com']
2019-12-06 11:45:17[DEBUG]django.db.backends.debug_sql(): (0.022) INSERT INTO "udjango_user" ("email") VALUES ('alice@example.com'); args=['alice@example.com']
2019-12-06 11:45:17[DEBUG]django.db.backends.debug_sql(): (0.022) INSERT INTO "udjango_user" ("email") VALUES ('bob@example.com'); args=['bob@example.com']
2019-12-06 11:45:17[DEBUG]django.db.backends.debug_sql(): (0.029) INSERT INTO "udjango_report" ("user_id") VALUES (1); args=[1]
2019-12-06 11:45:17[DEBUG]django.db.backends.debug_sql(): (0.033) INSERT INTO "udjango_report" ("user_id") VALUES (3); args=[3]
2019-12-06 11:45:17[DEBUG]django.db.backends.debug_sql(): (0.033) INSERT INTO "udjango_report" ("user_id") VALUES (3); args=[3]
2019-12-06 11:45:17[INFO]root.main(): users without reports
2019-12-06 11:45:17[DEBUG]django.db.backends.debug_sql(): (0.000) SELECT "udjango_user"."id", "udjango_user"."email" FROM "udjango_user" LEFT OUTER JOIN "udjango_report" ON ("udjango_user"."id" = "udjango_report"."user_id") WHERE ("udjango_user"."email" LIKE 'a%' ESCAPE '\' AND "udjango_report"."id" IS NULL) LIMIT 21; args=('a%',)
2019-12-06 11:45:17[INFO]root.main(): <QuerySet [User('adam@example.com')]>
2019-12-06 11:45:17[INFO]root.main(): users with reports (allows duplicates)
2019-12-06 11:45:17[DEBUG]django.db.backends.debug_sql(): (0.000) SELECT "udjango_user"."id", "udjango_user"."email" FROM "udjango_user" INNER JOIN "udjango_report" ON ("udjango_user"."id" = "udjango_report"."user_id") WHERE ("udjango_user"."email" LIKE 'a%' ESCAPE '\' AND "udjango_report"."id" IS NOT NULL) LIMIT 21; args=('a%',)
2019-12-06 11:45:17[INFO]root.main(): <QuerySet [User('anne@example.com'), User('alice@example.com'), User('alice@example.com')]>
2019-12-06 11:45:17[INFO]root.main(): users with reports (no duplicates)
2019-12-06 11:45:17[DEBUG]django.db.backends.debug_sql(): (0.000) SELECT "udjango_user"."id", "udjango_user"."email" FROM "udjango_user" WHERE (NOT ("udjango_user"."id" IN (SELECT U0."id" FROM "udjango_user" U0 LEFT OUTER JOIN "udjango_report" U1 ON (U0."id" = U1."user_id") WHERE U1."id" IS NULL)) AND "udjango_user"."email" LIKE 'a%' ESCAPE '\') LIMIT 21; args=('a%',)
2019-12-06 11:45:17[INFO]root.main(): <QuerySet [User('anne@example.com'), User('alice@example.com')]>
2019-12-06 11:45:17[INFO]root.main(): users with reports (no duplicates, simpler SQL)
2019-12-06 11:45:17[DEBUG]django.db.backends.debug_sql(): (0.000) SELECT "udjango_user"."id", "udjango_user"."email" FROM "udjango_user" WHERE ("udjango_user"."email" LIKE 'a%' ESCAPE '\' AND "udjango_user"."id" IN (SELECT U0."user_id" FROM "udjango_report" U0)) LIMIT 21; args=('a%',)
2019-12-06 11:45:17[INFO]root.main(): <QuerySet [User('anne@example.com'), User('alice@example.com')]>
2019-12-06 11:45:17[INFO]root.main(): users with reports (EXISTS clause, Django 3.0)
2019-12-06 11:45:17[DEBUG]django.db.backends.debug_sql(): (0.000) SELECT "udjango_user"."id", "udjango_user"."email" FROM "udjango_user" WHERE (EXISTS(SELECT U0."id", U0."user_id" FROM "udjango_report" U0 WHERE U0."user_id" = "udjango_user"."id") AND "udjango_user"."email" LIKE 'a%' ESCAPE '\') LIMIT 21; args=('a%',)
2019-12-06 11:45:17[INFO]root.main(): <QuerySet [User('anne@example.com'), User('alice@example.com')]>
2019-12-06 11:45:17[INFO]root.main(): Done.
```

You can see that the final query uses all inner joins.

Comment: It looks like your code snippet may not be complete. The last statement is `Report.objects.create(user=anne)` whereas your output and thoughts indicate that you intended to show more code. I am eager to see it!

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about, @KrystianCybulski. My browser shows about that much code, but then there's a scroll bar to see the rest. If you're having browser trouble, try editing the answer to see the Markdown source.

Comment: You are correct. I apologize. Chrome on Mac is clever and hides the scroll bar in the embedded code box. I did not realize it is scrollable.

Comment: And this, my friends, is true art —not the modern _"I get_ (buy|understand) _it and you don't"_ art, but the original, **artful display of mastery in your craft**, art.

This is no one-trick fish, but a fishing rod with a self contained testing pond, for anyone to easily demonstrate how to throw some lines, or try a few quick bug catching baits.  Well done Don.

Answer (score 1):

To filter users who do not have reports associated with them try this:

`users = User.objects.exclude(id__in=[elem.user.id for elem in Report.objects.all()])`

Comment: This is promising. I need to see what sort of SQL this would generate. I think also that `id__in = Report.objects.all()` will suffice for the `.exclude()` call.

Comment: If you use only `users=User.objects.exclude(id__in=Report.objects.all())` you will get all users which id is the same as any Report id

Comment: This is a bad answer, except when you're only going to use the website yourself, or within your closes friends ;) If you have 1 billion reports, this will probably crash the database. Rule of thumb: never use `__in=` in queries! Besides, you even dont have `Report.objects.values('user_id').distinct()`, which would help a bit with many reports but few users scenario.

Comment: I'd better improve on my "rule of thumb" - use `something__in=[my_value1, my_value2, ...]` only when you have a constant number of possibilities. This practically means that you are specifying it manually in some way. And OKAY - if you're passing a `queryset` object, this will actually turn into an SQL subquery, like: `WHERE "auth_user"."id" in (SELECT U0."id" FROM "report" U0)`. So you can still hope that the database makes sense of it.

Comment: For someone reading this answer: `[elem.user.id for elem in Report.objects.all()]` is highly inefficient - it fetches all fields from reports (when only one is needed), builds all `Report` instances for no good reason, and finally does one extra sql query per report to retrieve the user... `list(Report.objects.values_list('user_id', flat=True))` would solve all those issues (still not the best solution but...).

Answer (score 1):

#### The best option for finding rows where there *is* a joining row:

```
Report.objects.filter(user__isnull=False).distinct()
```

This uses an `INNER JOIN` (and then redundantly checks `User.id` is not null).

#### The best option for finding rows where there is *not* a joining row:

```
Report.objects.filter(user__isnull=True)
```

This makes `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, then checks `User.id` is not null.

Queries based on joins will be quicker than subqueries, so this is quicker than newly available options such as in Django >= 3, for finding rows *without* a joining row:

```
Report.objects.filter(~Exists(User.objects.filter(report=OuterRef('pk'))))
```

This creates a `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT .. FROM User..)` so involves a potentially large intermediate result set (thanks @Tomasz Gandor).

This for Django <3, where `filter()` can't be passed subqueries, also uses a subquery so is slower:

```
Report.objects.annotate(
    no_users=~Exists(User.objects.filter(report=OuterRef('pk')))
).filter(no_users=True)
```

This can be combined with subqueries. In this example, a `Textbook` has a number of `Versions` (ie, `version` has `textbook_id`), and a `version` has a number of `Pages` (ie, `page` has `version_id`). The subquery gets the latest version of each textbook that has pages associated:

```
subquery = (
    Version.objects
        .filter(
            # OuterRef joins to Version.textbook in outer query below
            textbook=OuterRef('textbook'), 
            # excludes rows with no joined Page records
            page__isnull=False)
        # ordered so [:1] below gets highest (ie, latest) version number
        .order_by('-number').distinct()
)
# Only the Version.ids of the latest versions that have pages returned by the subquery
books = Version.objects.filter(pk=Subquery(subquery.values('pk')[:1])).distinct()
```

To return rows that have a join to one or both of two tables, use Q objects (`Page` and `TextMarkup` both have nullable foreign keys joining to `File`):

```
from django.db.models import Q

File.objects.filter(Q(page__isnull=False) | Q(textmarkup__isnull=False).distinct()
```