# Get objects that are not in manytomany relationship of a different model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Lets say I have two models and a form:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name      = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name       = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Car(models.Model):
    plate   = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    persons = models.ManyToManyField(Person)
```

```
class CarAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    plate           = forms.CharField()
    persons         = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Person.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = [
            'plate',
            'persons'
        ]
```

Is there a way to get ModelMultipleChoiceField queryset of people that are NOT associated with any car?
In case of editing Car model object, the queryset should contain people that are NOT associated with any car PLUS people that are associated with the car being edited

PS: maybe there is a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In a Django QuerySet, how to filter for “not exists” in a many-to-one relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831327/in-a-django-queryset-how-to-filter-for-not-exists-in-a-many-to-one-relationsh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [**`limit_choices_to`**--(Doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/) argument of **`ManyToManyField`** as

```
class Car(models.Model):
    plate = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    persons = models.ManyToManyField(
        Person,
        limit_choices_to={"car__isnull": True}
    )
```

Alternatively, you can also alter the **`queryset`** argument of **`ModelMultipleChoiceField`** as

```
class CarAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    plate = forms.CharField()
    persons = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Person.objects.filter(car__isnull=True)
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = [
            'plate',
            'persons'
        ]
```

Comment: Thanks `queryset=Person.objects.filter(car__isnull=True)` is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Regards the editing part I created another form CarEditForm that inherits CarAddForm and in the __init__ method changed the queryset to `self.fields['persons'].queryset |= self.instance.persons.all()`

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a filter for the query:

```
from django.db import models

class CarAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    persons = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Person.objects\
            .annotate(car_count=models.Count('cars'))\
            .filter(car_count=0))
    ...
```

---

Another options is to override the forms `__init__()` method. Maybe like this:

```
from django.db import models

class CarAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['person'].queryset = self.fields['person'].queryset\
            .annotate(car_count=models.Count('cars'))\
            .filter(car_count=0))
```

Comment: I wouldn't do a *count()* query since I can get the same result with a filter condition.