# Django model data query Exclude objects which are connected to another model by ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have two django models named Quiz and Result

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

another model

```
class Result(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='results')
```

Now i want to query data from this in two ways

1. I want all the Quiz objects which do not have a Result
2. I want all the Quiz objects which have a Result

How can I do this?

Comment: your request is [place](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14832060/11831226)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the results you want by using these queries...

View.py

```
from django.db.models import Q

results_obj= Result.objects.all()
quiz_without_result = Quiz.objects.exclude(id__in=results_obj)
quiz_with_result = Quiz.objects.filter(Q(id__in=results_obj))
```

First of all, we will fetch all the results, then we can get the quizzes with a condition that they should not contain any quiz that exists in results_obj

Then we can use Q (that represents or statement for Django queries) to get quizzes that do have results